# FlexNav without

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using [FlexNav](http://jasonweaver.name/lab/flexiblenavigation/). The width of top level menu items is set to `20%` in the demo, so it is optimized for five top level menu items.

```
.flexnav li {
    .
    .
    .
    width: 20%;
}
```

In my menu the top level menu item texts have different lengths and the child elements (level 2) are wider that their parents. I'm trying to make the menu more flexible, so it isn't necessary to define the top level menu items' width. But without fixed with the menu doesn't work right. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flexnav").flexNav({ 'calcItemWidths' : true });
});
</script>

<ul class="flexnav" data-breakpoint="800">
    <li>Menu Item 1</li>
    <li>Menu Item 2</li>
    <li>Menu Item 3</li>
    <li>Menu Item 4</li>
    <li>Menu Item 5</li>
    <li>Menu Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

When you set the option `calcItemWidths` to `true`, the plugin should calculate the width of the menu items.

Answer (score -1):

There shouldn't be any reason to leave off the widths on the parents; FlexNav is already setup so that long children will wrap:

[image: A Very Long Child]

As a bit of an aside, in general UX terms you probably don't want terribly long names in menu items, anyway.

Comment: There's an option called `calcItemWidths` which solves this issue